# Naming database fields

Tags: database, entity-framework, naming-conventions

I'm trying to be as much as consistent as possible at naming the tables of a new database.

As of today I've named all the tables with plurals, like the following:

- Persons
- Companies
- Products
- Shops

Now I have a table that contains the **units of measure** of the products, i.e. Kilogram, Liter, Pound, Meter.

How can I name it to keep the same standard and in order that EntityFramework is able to convert plural to singular for the class objects?

Comment: `ProductUnits` can be a good and meaningful name as @Bug Catcher suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ProductUnits** would be a good name then.